# Difference between a "general" and a "generic" confidential letter of recommendation?

Tags: job-search, recommendation-letter, faculty-application, reference-request

In the context of applications to tenure-track assistant professorship positions in computer science in the US, I see both terms:

- general confidential letter of recommendation
- generic confidential letter of recommendation

What is the difference in the meaning of the terms?

Comment: They look like synonyms to me.

Comment: In math, I don't think I've see the term "general letter."  (Also confidential is assumed, so I rarely see that explicated as well.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference.  They both refer to a letter that discusses the applicant's achievements and qualifications for a general type of job (postdoc, assistant professor, etc) without being tailored to the expectations of a particular employer.